# Fastest way to reset an AWS RDS instance to an initial state?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm experimenting with creating a staging version of a simple postgres RDS backed CRUD web app on elastic beanstalk. The aim of this staging version is to run integration tests against when implementing new code changes, before redeploying these changes to the production environment.

The current problem I have is reseting the staging stack. I want a blank DB instance at the start of my integration tests. Redeploying a new RDS instance however takes several minutes which means the integration tests take a long time (>20 minutes) to run.

Since it's on elastic beanstalk it's in a VPC and therefore to reset the DB with SQL commands it seems like the CI server would have to do some tricky stuff with ssh tunnels which doesn't (at least to me) that simple either.

Is there a fast way to reset a running RDS instance to a blank state for the purpose of testing?

Comment: There's nothing built in. Basically you have 2 options: (a) create a fresh instance, or (b) empty the existing one via SQL commands.

Comment: we still need a good automated solution for this unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

I think that what you want is to have the blank database (vs the blank RDS instance) and here there are few options to do this:

1) Best option IMO, but may require some coding - postgresql supports savepoints, so you can structure your tests that they will always preserve the database clean (also useful for local tests). The idea is to create a savepoint before starting the tests and rollback to that savepoint at the end. This way all the changes made by tests will be removed.

2) When your tests start you can run SQL commands to drop / create the database. Your tests can connect to the database, so you can do this from your code, there is not need to do this via ssh. If data amount is small, you can create a new database for each test run. You can name it like "mydb20160115101112" (with current date and time).

3) Drop/create databse should actually be possible from the CI configuration too (also without ssh or other complex stuff), you staging instance already has access to the RDS, so you can just run some SQL commands using `psql`, something like this:

`psql -c "drop database mydb20160115101112;" --dbname=template1`

To use psql this way (without having to enter a username/password), you need to create a postgresql user with same name as you system user (make sure you create a postgresql for the system user the CI uses).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions these are good ideas. This seems to rely on connecting to the RDS instance through the VPC which I am not very familiar with.

Comment: @Michael Barton Actually I meant that you don't need anything like vpc or ssh to do it. You code is able to connect to the RDS via postgre client libraries and read/write data, right? So you can use the same way to drop/create the db or use psql tool from the shell script.

Comment: Are you sure you will not face problems with RDS in MultiAZ?

Comment: You can't drop the currently active database in Amazon RDS. If you try to kill the database first before killing it you're booted from the RDS instance and it's automatically reset back to its initial state. So the best part of this answer is the roll back functionality but I was having a lot of trouble with that.

Comment: @jgomo3 most probably you don't need the MultiAZ to run tests, but even if you do, I don't think there can be a problem creating / dropping the database.

Comment: @anon58192932 you can have multiple databases within the same RDS instance, there is no problem creating / dropping databases, I did this although for a different use case.

Comment: the error message is `cannot drop currently open table`. the resolution for that error message on SO does not work on RDS SQL. It boots you from the Postgres connection and performs a reset.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov the problem with that is that AWS manage only your first database in theory, so they will not support the others. They do, but are not forced to backup them. Also, the metrics you receive from them... I'm not sure if they monitor the other databases and then you could be mislead by those numbers... So, it is possible that in MultiAZ they will not guarantee correct replication in other databases. All this is just "fear" from intuition. I would like to know if this is true.

Comment: @jgomo3 backup for sure includes all the databases, they do the instance snapshots, not individual DB backups. Same is true for the monitoring - it is on the DB instance level. 
In any case, I assume this question and answer are about non-production scenarios (running tests, development, etc).
For production, it is better to have 1 DB per instance and, if you need to restore the DB to the previous state, use the RDS snapshots.

Answer (score 3):

If you create your RDS instance with the help of Elastic Beanstalk then consider my solution. This will not work with an external created and connected RDS.

For my use case, I found a very simple solution by simply rebuilding an EB environment through the console. This automatically creates a new RDS database instance with the same settings but it does not apply any snapshots and thus the new database is empty. This was very useful when applying new migrations with Django.

Hope this is helpful, more information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-management-rebuild.html .